# Google Script: Getting attributes from anchor tag

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this text appended to a document:

```
<a target="_blank" class="title" href="http://www.dabcc.com/citrix-generating-images-for-xenserver-in-openstack/" h="ID=news,5175.2">Citrix: Generating Images for XenServer in OpenStack</a>
<a target="_blank" class="title" href="https://www.virtualizationpractice.com/citrix-acquires-norskale-39055/" h="ID=news,5184.1">Citrix Acquires Norskale</a>
```

I am trying to get link url, which is `"http://www.dabcc.com/citrix-generating...` for the first one.

That's how I get everything inside `a`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < XmlService.parse(buffer).getDescendants().length; i++) {
    doc.appendParagraph(XmlService.parse(buffer).getDescendants()[i]);
  }
```

This shows me this:

```
[Element: <a/>]
Citrix: Generating Images for XenServer in OpenStack
[Element: <a/>]
Citrix Acquires Norskale
```

How can I separate text and url? As you can see, text is separated in the above example. How can I get url? Is there a safer/better way to get all attributes?

Please let me know if additional info needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way:

```
var link = Xml.parse(buffer[i]).getElement().getAttribute('href').getValue());
var text = Xml.parse(buffer[i]).getElement().getText();
```

[Element Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getAttribute(String))